# Mouseover Tooltip jquery (tipsy)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I tried executing a Jquery tooltip code on marker hover, however I think that the problem lies in setting the position.

Here's my code

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function () {
    $('#example-1').tipsy();
        });
```

The MOUSEOVER code itself works, but I think that I might need to set the position of the tooltip?

The plugin can be found here:
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the element needs to be on the map.

For an illustration of how to do this look at the Custom Info Window Example, Google for:

Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example Info Window Custom

Comment: Hmm, I could ideally load the infowindow on mouseover and close it on mouseleave, then style it in css to look like a tooltip. Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone still need a solution. This is how I solve it.

First, define a listener, for hover event on "areas" in your map layer

```
$(dom).on('hover', 'area', function () {
    var $this = $(this), title = $this.attr('title');
    if (title) {
        $this.removeAttr('title');

        // this is the best dom node I figured out to attach the tipsy (and trigger this very first time)
        $this.parent().parent().attr('title', title).tipsy().tipsy("show");
    }
});
```

When you add your maker, do it without optimization:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: title,
    position: location,
    // make maps to create a DOM node for each marker
    optimized: false
});
```

Thats all!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing an extra library to get tooltips for the map, you might have better luck just using the `InfoWindow` object that is part of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Another, even easier (but less feature-rich) option is to use the default tooltip functionality for `Marker` objects.  Simply set the `title` property on your Marker and your done.

```
marker.setTitle('rollover text!!!');
```

(If you truly need some functionality in tipsy that isn't available using `InfoWindow`, it would probably be good to include what that functionality is in the question and/or a comment.)

Comment: Thanks, I currently am using the title property although I don't like the display delay time and the default look of the windows tooltip. What I was trying to do is this: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/